matplotlib で箱ひげ図の目盛り位置を左揃えにしたい
matplotlibを使用した箱ひげ図の目盛り位置についてご教授お願い致します。
箱ひげ図を作成するため以下のコードを記述しました。
縦軸の目盛りの文字（1sample...）を文字数が異なるため左揃えにしたいのですが、ha="left" を追加すると、plotエリアも全て左に寄ってしまうので困っています。
# coding: UTF-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

x5 = [100, 50, 100, 600, 200, 90, 130, 30, 90, 100, 50, 60, 140]
x4 = [100, 20, 60, 90, 200, 250, 93.6, 93.6, 93.6, 124.8, 124.8, 93.6, 93.6]
x3 = [146, 43.8, 200, 87.6, 100, 175.2, 87, 42, 56, 84, 70, 84, 112]
x2 = [78, 19.5, 52, 97, 227.5, 104, 156, 126, 75.6, 113.4, 126, 30, 100]
x1 = [180, 54, 210, 72, 54, 168, 72, 89, 60, 50, 90, 49, 132]
data = (x1, x2,x3,x4,x5) 

ax1.boxplot((data),vert=False,patch_artist=True,
            showmeans=True,
            boxprops=dict(facecolor='white',  # boxの塗りつぶし色の設定
                       color='black', linewidth=1),
            medianprops=dict(color='black', linewidth=1),#中央値の線の色
            meanprops=dict(markeredgecolor='black',marker='x',markersize=3))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=25)
# x 軸のラベルを設定する。
ax1.set_xlabel("RPN ",fontname="Arial")


# y 軸のラベルを設定する。
ax1.set_ylabel("Failure mode",fontname="Arial")
#日本語の場合("Y軸",fontname="MS Gothic")

#横軸の値を日本語にする場合
fp = FontProperties(fname=r'C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\msgothic.ttc')
ax1.set_yticks([1,2,3,4,5])

ax1.set_yticklabels(
    ['1samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample','2samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample','3samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample','4samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample','5samplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesamplesample'],
    fontproperties=fp,
    fontsize=8,ha="left"
    )

ax1.tick_params(direction = "out")

plt.savefig("箱ひげ横向き.tiff",format="tiff",dpi=500,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()


SOのこちらの回答によれば Aligning y-ticks to the left
ax1.tick_params(direction = "out")

# 以降, 追加分
yax = ax1.get_yaxis()
# find the maximum width of the label on the major ticks
pad = max(T.label1.get_window_extent().width for T in yax.majorTicks)

yax.set_tick_params(pad=pad)


うまく動かない場合の対処
以下の計算は, colabで試すと最大 1260.125 くらいの配列
yax = ax1.get_yaxis()
ws = [T.label1.get_window_extent().width for T in yax.majorTicks]

このため次のような指定で描画すると大体収まります
yax.set_tick_params(pad=920)


どのような数値なのか調べる
他の環境 (例えば colab)で動作確認行ってみる

など対処してみると良いかも

** update

今度はRuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o rendererが発生してしまいました。

Matplotlibのバージョンが旧いのでしょう (この回答の時点で最新は 3.8(3.8.4))
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'3.8.4'

Matplotlibのバージョンを変えずに対処するには先のpadだけの指定で調整できるはず
("Cannot get window extent w/o renderer" が出るのは, .label1.get_window_extent()を呼び出してるからでは？)
yax.set_tick_params(pad=920)


ご回答ありがとうございます。入力したところ今度はRuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o rendererが発生してしまいました。

spyderを使用しているのですが、Plotsタブに表示されているグラフのyticklabelsはやはり左寄せにはなっていませんね。

google colab下ですとご提案いただいた方法でうまくいきましたありがとうございました。

yax.set_tick_params(pad=920) (数値は適当)を spyderで試すとどうなりますか？

RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o rendererが発生してグラフはプロットエリアも左寄せになったままでした。
